# lambda calculus of (Lx.xfx)(Lf.xf)(Lx.xf)

Tags: lambda-calculus

i'd like to ask why this lambda expression:
`(Lx.xfx)(Lf.xf)(Lx.xf)` is redused in normal form in this way:

```
-> (Lf.xf)f(Lf.xf)(Lx.xf)

-> (xf)(Lf.xf)(Lx.xf)
```

Why do I stop here? why do I not apply `(Lf.xf)(Lx.xf)` and get `(xf)(x(Lx.xf))` ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because (xf)(Lf.xf)(Lx.xf) is (xf(Lf.xf))(Lx.xf).  You don't know what will come out of (xf)(Lf.xf).  Expression evaluation is not associative.

Comment: so the role is "first evaluate the inner parentesis on the left" ? I mena: if i have `x y z`, it is like `(((x)y)z` ?

Comment: Yes, you always evaluate the leftmost function.  If you have  `x y z`, you apply x to y, then z to the result.